# Solve for a complex number $z$ in $z+z_1|z_2|=0$ with $z_1=cis(\frac{2\pi}{3})$ and $z_2=2cis(\frac{5\pi}{4})$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$z+z_1|z_2|=0\Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot cis(\theta)+cis(\frac{2\pi}{3})\cdot2cis(-\frac{5\pi}{4})=0\Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot cis(\theta)+2cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{5\pi}{4})=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot cis(\theta)+2cis(-\frac{7\pi}{12})=0\Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot  cis(\theta)=-2cis(-\frac{7\pi}{12}) \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot   cis(\theta)= 2cis(-\frac{7\pi}{12}+\pi) \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho\cdot   cis(\theta)= 2cis(\frac{5\pi}{12})$$

Now my book wants me to put this in the $x+yi$ form and states that the solution is $1-\sqrt{3}i$.

$$2cis(\frac{5\pi}{12}) = 2(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{12})+\sin(\frac{5\pi}{12})i)=2(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}i)=\\
\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}i$$

What went wrong?

Comment: The norm of $z_2$ is 2 i.e. $|z_2|=2$

Comment: @Ixion Oh right, I confused the conjugate with the magnitude... sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus of $\operatorname{cis}\alpha$ is $1$. So $|z_2|=2$ and your equation becomes
$$
z=-2z_1=-2\operatorname{cis}\frac{2\pi}{3}=
-2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)=1-\sqrt{3}\,i
$$
because
$$
\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}=-\frac{1}{2}
\qquad
\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$